Changing variables in C++ code with HTML buttons
Apologies if I get any terminology wrong, I'm a total beginner. I have an Arduino IDE sketch in C++, written for an ESP32-WROVER-CAM. A secondary C++ file in the same folder sets up an HTTP server and hosts an HTML page. I'm attempting to use HTML buttons to modify variables in the C++ code.
I've Googled and tried various HTML scripts, adding extra handlers, functions, and URIs. The variable I'm trying to change still remains at 0 instead of 1.
Most of the code was already present as I'm using a code example from the manufacturer (Freenove), I'm just attempting to add extra functionality. The extern int variables are from the main .ino file.
HTML portion of the file:
const char index_web[] =
  "\
<html>\
  <head>\
    <title>ESP32 Camera</title>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <h1>ESP32 Camera</h1>\
    <img src=\"/stream\"\"/><br>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(0)\">Automatic mode</button><br>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(1)\">Manual mode</button>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(2)\">Move left</button>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(3)\">Move right</button><br>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(4)\">Transmit audio</button>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(5)\">Stop audio</button>\
  </body>\
</html>\

Secondary C++ file:
#include "esp_http_server.h"
#include "esp_timer.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "img_converters.h"
#include "fb_gfx.h"
#include "driver/ledc.h"

#include "sdkconfig.h"

#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32) && defined(CONFIG_ARDUHAL_ESP_LOG)
#include "esp32-hal-log.h"
#define TAG ""
#else
#include "esp_log.h"
static const char *TAG = "camera_httpd";
#endif

extern int mode;
extern int left;
extern int right;

typedef struct
{
  httpd_req_t *req;
  size_t len;
} jpg_chunking_t;

#define PART_BOUNDARY "123456789000000000000987654321"
static const char *_STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=" PART_BOUNDARY;
static const char *_STREAM_BOUNDARY = "\r\n--" PART_BOUNDARY "\r\n";
static const char *_STREAM_PART = "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: %u\r\nX-Timestamp: %d.%06d\r\n\r\n";

httpd_handle_t stream_httpd = NULL;
httpd_handle_t camera_httpd = NULL;

typedef struct
{
  size_t size;   // number of values used for filtering
  size_t index;  // current value index
  size_t count;  // value count
  int sum;
  int *values;  // array to be filled with values
} ra_filter_t;

static ra_filter_t ra_filter;

static ra_filter_t *ra_filter_init(ra_filter_t *filter, size_t sample_size) {
  memset(filter, 0, sizeof(ra_filter_t));

  filter->values = (int *)malloc(sample_size * sizeof(int));
  if (!filter->values) {
    return NULL;
  }
  memset(filter->values, 0, sample_size * sizeof(int));

  filter->size = sample_size;
  return filter;
}

static int ra_filter_run(ra_filter_t *filter, int value) {
  if (!filter->values) {
    return value;
  }
  filter->sum -= filter->values[filter->index];
  filter->values[filter->index] = value;
  filter->sum += filter->values[filter->index];
  filter->index++;
  filter->index = filter->index % filter->size;
  if (filter->count < filter->size) {
    filter->count++;
  }
  return filter->sum / filter->count;
}

static esp_err_t stream_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {
  camera_fb_t *fb = NULL;
  struct timeval _timestamp;
  esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
  size_t _jpg_buf_len = 0;
  uint8_t *_jpg_buf = NULL;
  char *part_buf[128];

  static int64_t last_frame = 0;
  if (!last_frame) {
    last_frame = esp_timer_get_time();
  }

  res = httpd_resp_set_type(req, _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE);
  if (res != ESP_OK) {
    return res;
  }

  httpd_resp_set_hdr(req, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  httpd_resp_set_hdr(req, "X-Framerate", "60");

  while (true) {
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb) {
      ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Camera capture failed");
      res = ESP_FAIL;
    } else {
      _timestamp.tv_sec = fb->timestamp.tv_sec;
      _timestamp.tv_usec = fb->timestamp.tv_usec;
      if (fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG) {
        bool jpeg_converted = frame2jpg(fb, 80, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);
        esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
        fb = NULL;
        if (!jpeg_converted) {
          ESP_LOGE(TAG, "JPEG compression failed");
          res = ESP_FAIL;
        }
      } else {
        _jpg_buf_len = fb->len;
        _jpg_buf = fb->buf;
      }
    }
    if (res == ESP_OK) {
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, _STREAM_BOUNDARY, strlen(_STREAM_BOUNDARY));
    }
    if (res == ESP_OK) {
      size_t hlen = snprintf((char *)part_buf, 128, _STREAM_PART, _jpg_buf_len, _timestamp.tv_sec, _timestamp.tv_usec);
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)part_buf, hlen);
    }
    if (res == ESP_OK) {
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)_jpg_buf, _jpg_buf_len);
    }
    if (fb) {
      esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
      fb = NULL;
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    } else if (_jpg_buf) {
      free(_jpg_buf);
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    }
    if (res != ESP_OK) {
      ESP_LOGI(TAG, "res != ESP_OK : %d , break!", res);
      break;
    }
    int64_t fr_end = esp_timer_get_time();

    int64_t frame_time = fr_end - last_frame;
    last_frame = fr_end;
    frame_time /= 1000;
    uint32_t avg_frame_time = ra_filter_run(&ra_filter, frame_time);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "MJPG: %uB %ums (%.1ffps), AVG: %ums (%.1ffps)",
             (uint32_t)(_jpg_buf_len),
             (uint32_t)frame_time, 1000.0 / (uint32_t)frame_time,
             avg_frame_time, 1000.0 / avg_frame_time);
  }
  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Stream exit!");
  last_frame = 0;
  return res;
}

static esp_err_t parse_get(httpd_req_t *req, char **obuf) {
  char *buf = NULL;
  size_t buf_len = 0;

  buf_len = httpd_req_get_url_query_len(req) + 1;
  if (buf_len > 1) {
    buf = (char *)malloc(buf_len);
    if (!buf) {
      httpd_resp_send_500(req);
      return ESP_FAIL;
    }
    if (httpd_req_get_url_query_str(req, buf, buf_len) == ESP_OK) {
      *obuf = buf;
      return ESP_OK;
    }
    free(buf);
  }
  httpd_resp_send_404(req);
  return ESP_FAIL;
}

const char index_web[] =
  "\
<html>\
  <head>\
    <title>ESP32 Camera</title>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <h1>ESP32 Camera</h1>\
    <img src=\"/stream\"\"/><br>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(0)\">Automatic mode</button><br>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(1)\">Manual mode</button>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(2)\">Move left</button>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(3)\">Move right</button><br>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(4)\">Transmit audio</button>\
    <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sendRequest(5)\">Stop audio</button>\
  </body>\
</html>\
";

static esp_err_t index_handler(httpd_req_t *req) {
  httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
  // httpd_resp_set_hdr(req, "Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  sensor_t *s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  if (s != NULL) {
    // return httpd_resp_sendstr(req, (const char *)index_web);
    return httpd_resp_send(req, (const char *)index_web, sizeof(index_web));
    // return httpd_resp_send(req, (const char *)index_ov2640_html_gz, index_ov2640_html_gz_len);
  } else {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Camera sensor not found");
    return httpd_resp_send_500(req);
  }
}

void startCameraServer() {
  httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
  config.max_uri_handlers = 16;

  httpd_uri_t index_uri = {
    .uri = "/",
    .method = HTTP_GET,
    .handler = index_handler,
    .user_ctx = NULL
  };

  httpd_uri_t stream_uri = {
    .uri = "/stream",
    .method = HTTP_GET,
    .handler = stream_handler,
    .user_ctx = NULL
  };
  ra_filter_init(&ra_filter, 20);

  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting web server on port: '%d'", config.server_port);
  if (httpd_start(&camera_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
    httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &index_uri);
    httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &stream_uri);
  }
}

Original example code that I'm modifying.

please show a [mre]. Where is sendRequest defined? Which variable are you attempting to change?

I'm attempting to change the extern ints mode, left, and right. As for the sendRequest, I'm not entirely certain on how it's supposed to work. It's a leftover from some code of 
@ACF15 This is the issue, it doesn't work. It's code that you have to define.

@ACF15 How you define it depends on the server side code (and perhaps also requires the server side code to be modified). Unfortunately I'm not competant enough to tell you precisely what you need to do.

Where is the JavaScript code for sendRequest? Do you see error messages in the console for a missing function definition? Why do you use malloc in C++?

You need to setup ajax in additional to plain html to capture the user input and send it back to the server.  On the server, in addition to the / route which serves the html, you need to setup another route (e.g. /data) and handle the received response. See WebServer example for more details.

@hcheung AJAX is only one option. There are others, e.g. forms.

@jabaa how would I go about using forms to change variables in the C++ code?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

@ACF15 Forms uses a technology called CGI. As mentioned by hcheung AJAX is another technology that can make this work. In my opinion what you need to do is spend some time learning about one of these options, i.e. read a tutorial about how it works, so you can then write your own original code. Of the two CGI is the simpler option. I see too many beginners who think that they can copy some existing code and then, with no real understanding of what they are doing, adapt the code to their needs. Seems this rarely works.

@john No, CGI is one way to handle forms. Another way is routing. Forms are very common with PHP but PHP usually doesn't use CGI.

If you want to know how write a web app that can communicate with a backend using HTTP, it's a separate HTML and JavaScript question that's unrelated to C++. If you want to know how to write a C++ backend that can handle HTTP requests it's a separate C++ question that's unrelated to HTML and JavaScript. Split your complex problem into multiple simpler problems and solve the simpler problems.
